# Is there an elegant way to check which elements in an array are in another container?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm sure the same or a similar question has been asked many times, but maybe my phrasing is off, so I didn't find a fitting post yet.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np


students = np.array(
    [('Jim', 2), ('John', 3), ('Lisa', 5), ('Laura', 1)],
    dtype=[('name', 'O'), ('grade', 'i4')]
)

# this works
good_students = students[students['grade'] < 3]

# this doesn't because unfortunately, numpy doesn't understand that I want 
# it to do elementwise comparison
# absent_students = students[students['name'] in ['John', 'Laura']]

# this does but is ugly
absent_students = np.array(
    [], dtype=[('name', 'O'), ('grade', 'i4')]
)
for name in ['John', 'Laura']:
    absent_students = np.append(
        absent_students, students[students['name'] == name]
    )
```

Is there a better way than manually looping over the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [np.isin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
absent_students = students[np.isin(students['name'],['John', 'Laura'])]
print(absent_students)
```

**Output**

```
[('John', 3) ('Laura', 1)]
```

As an alternative the flattened version, [np.in1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html#numpy.in1d):

```
absent_students = students[np.in1d(students['name'],['John', 'Laura'])]
print(absent_students)
```

**Output**

```
[('John', 3) ('Laura', 1)]
```

**UPDATE**

Notice that this won't work if the *test_elements*, i.e. `['John', 'Laura']`, is a set. From the documentation:

> If test_elements is a set (or other non-sequence collection) it will
> be converted to an object array with one element, rather than an array
> of the values contained in test_elements. This is a consequence of the
> array constructor’s way of handling non-sequence collections.
> Converting the set to a list usually gives the desired behavior.

Comment: Quick question: why does this not work when the container to compare with is a `set`?

Comment: @mapf Update the answer.